# Unity3d with Firebase: Can't Start Coroutine

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Greeting,

I'm currently facing a problem that my coroutine can't start. This is the first time I facing this issues and I can't find a proper solution online. Much appreciated if anyone can point me to the right direction to solve this issue.

Here are the code.

```
path_reference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> task) => {

if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);

                StartCoroutine(DownloadStuff(task.Result));
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }
        });
    }
```

```
IEnumerator DownloadStuff(Uri uri)
{
    Debug.Log("Start Download");

    using (var www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(uri))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);

            //Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);

            //if you need sprite for SpriteRenderer or Image
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width,
                    texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
            Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
        }

        Debug.Log(www.downloadProgress);
    }
}'
```

Comment: When you say 'can't start?' what do you mean exactly? What happens when you try running it?

Comment: The codes run, but when it supposed to start the coroutine, nothing happened.

Comment: Are any of the Debug messages given?

Comment: NO, even at the Coroutine "Debug.Log("Start Download");" doesn't even appear.

Comment: It looks like the coroutine is being called correctly so the problem is probably somewhere else. By "NO" do you mean not even ``Debug.Log("Download URL: etc..``? If so then the problem is definitely elsewhere. Try changing ``!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled`` to ``true``

Comment: My apologizes.  `Debug.Log("Download URL: etc..` this part work.
is after that Debug, its not running the Coroutine.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Noted, I will edit now.

Answer (score 0):

The task returned by Firebase probably finishes execution on a thread other than the main thread, and Unity coroutines can only run on the main thread.

Unity's support of multithreading and async is pretty spotty, including "eating" some errors if the continuations of those errors would execute on another thread other than the main thread.

To fix this, you need to change the function that starts your coroutine:

```cs
try {
    // Important: ConfigureAwait(true) ensures the code after this will run in the
    // same thread as the code before (which is the main thread!)
    var url = await path_reference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
    StartCoroutine(DownloadStuff(url));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Tip: when logging errors, use LogException and pass the whole exception,
    // that way you will get pretty links to the error line in the whole stack trace.
    Debug.LogException(ex);
}
```

---

As an aside, I usually have a few extension methods on all my projects to deal with that while staying in async-world instead of coroutine-world (because at least with async I can catch errors and not just "halt and catch fire" like Unity's coroutines)

The main ones are:

```cs
public static Task ToTask(this YieldInstruction self, MonoBehaviour owner) {
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    IEnumerable Routine() {
        yield return self;
        source.SetResult(null);
    }

    return source.Task;
}

private static Task SendAsync(this UnityWebRequest self, MonoBehaviour owner) {
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    await self.SendWebRequest().ToTask(owner);

    if (
        self.isHttpError
        || self.isNetworkError
    ) {
        source.SetException(new Exception(request.error));
        yield break;
    }

    source.SetResult(null);
}
```

Which you can use like this, inside a `MonoBehaviour`:

```cs
await new WaitForSeconds(0.2f).ToTask(this);

UnityWebRequest request = /* etc */;
await request.SendAsync(this);
var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(request);
```

Note that these methods do not require `ConfigureAwait`, since their `SetResult`/`SetException` invocations are ran from Unity-provided coroutine continuations.

Comment: `try
        {

            path_reference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> task) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);
               

 // ... now download the file via WWW or UnityWebRequest.

                StartCoroutine(DownloadStuff(task.Result));
            });

            }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogException(ex);
        }
`

So, I do it like this?
@Kroltan

Comment: No, don't use `ContinueWith`, since with that you can't change the `ConfigureAwait`. You have to mark your outer method with `async` so you can `await` the task returned from `GetDownloadUrlAsync`.